# how to get records from between two dates in two columns using mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have two columns like START_DATE and END_DATE

example

- Record1 contains 2018-06-18 and 2018-06-20
- Record2 contains 2018-06-19 and 2018-07-23
- Record3 contains 2018-06-14 and 2018-06-26

if my filter is set between 2018-06-16 and 2018-07-23

how to fetch two records by using which query? i want record1 and record2 only

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Comparison Operators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html) to filter between dates.

- `>` - Greater than
- `>=` - Greater than or equal
- `<` - less than
- `<=` - less than or equal

Try,

```
... WHERE datetime > '2018-06-16' AND datetime <= '2018-07-23'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `objects`
WHERE (date_field BETWEEN '2010-01-30 14:15:55' AND '2010-09-29 10:15:55')
```